# How to use a search window in numpy and retain the maximum value and all the other values to zero

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a two-dimensional array eg (101 rows and 100 columns). Now I want to create a search window or block of (3 rows x 3 columns) that will move around the array and determine the highest value, select it and retain all other values as zeros using python and numpy. For  example

```
x = ([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
     [2,5,4,5,3,4,6,7,5,3],
     [3,3,4,5,6,7,3,4,5,8]]
```

Using  a 2x2 search window x.somefunction for example starting from the top left will  give a result

```
Result = ([0,0...
          [0,5... for the 1st iteration so the the whole result should look like this 


Result = ([[0,0,0,0,0,6,0,8,0,10],
           [0,5,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0],
           [3,3,0,5,0,7,0,4,0,8]]
```

Notice that that the last row the search window had to change from a 2x2 array to a 2x1 because the search window is non-overlapping

Your help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `skimage.util.view_as_blocks`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import skimage.util as su
>>> 
>>> def split_axis(N, n):
...     q, r = divmod(N, n)
...     left = ((np.s_[:q*n], n),) if q else ()
...     right = ((np.s_[q*n:], r),) if r else ()
...     return (*left, *right)
... 
>>> def block_max(x, block, inplace=False):
...     if not inplace:
...         x = x.copy()
...     xi, xj = x.shape
...     bi, bj = block
...     for ci, ri in split_axis(xi, bi):
...         for cj, rj in split_axis(xj, bj):
...             vab = su.view_as_blocks(x[ci, cj], (ri, rj))
...             vab[vab < vab.max(axis=(-1, -2), keepdims=True)] = 0
...     return x
... 
>>> x = ([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
...      [2,5,4,5,3,4,6,7,5,3],
...      [3,3,4,5,6,7,3,4,5,8]])
>>> 
>>> x = np.array(x)
>>> 
>>> block_max(x, (2, 2))
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  6,  0,  8,  0, 10],
       [ 0,  5,  0,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  3,  0,  5,  0,  7,  0,  4,  0,  8]])
```

If you don't have `skimage`:

```
>>> def view_as_blocks(x, blockshape):
...     *xs, xi, xj = x.shape
...     bi, bj = blockshape
...     return np.ascontiguousarray(x).reshape(*xs, xi//bi, xj//bj, *blockshape)
```

Your updated question (untested):

```
>>> def block_max(x, block):
...     out = np.zeros_like(x)
...     xi, xj = x.shape
...     bi, bj = block
...     for ci, ri in split_axis(xi, bi):
...         for cj, rj in split_axis(xj, bj):
...             vab = su.view_as_blocks(x[ci, cj], (ri, rj))
...             oab = su.view_as_blocks(out[ci, cj], (ri, rj))
...             vmx = vab.max(axis=(-1, -2), keepdims=True)
...             vmn = vab.min(axis=(-1, -2), keepdims=True)
...             cond = vmx - vmn > 2
...             oab[cond & (vab == vmx)] == 1
...             oab[cond & (vab == vmn)] == 2
...     return out
```

Comment: Thank you . Did not have skimage , i guess i have to install the package. Just a quick question. How can i modify the code to select the maximum and the minimum  in a search window . If the difference is eg using the array x above lets say 2. Return the maximum value as 1 and minimum as 2  .. all the other values to 0. If the condition is not mate ,return an empty array (return all values as zeros )